# String replace(single quotes) function in php

Tags: php, str-replace, single-quotes

I wan't to replace both quotes in unique format using php

```
$f1= "Alva’s Institute of Engineering & Technology (AIET)";
$f1= "Alva's Institute Of Engineering & Technology";
```

I tried str_replace function, but it not applicable for both quotes: `str_replace("’","&#39;",$f1)`, how can i replace both quotes???

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Do use an array for the search `str_replace(array("’","'"),"&#39;",$f1)`

Comment: Or using `preg_replace("/’|'/", "&#39;", $f1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to lookup for more than one string with `str_replace` like:

```
print str_replace(array("’","'"),"&#39;",$f1);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @Ranju Maybe `.

Comment: @Ranju Thing you have to google that. In mind comes `´ \``